# Access PME Metadata in Pivot4J/Saiku

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I am using Pentaho BI Server 5.0.1 with the Pivot4J plug-in for Pentaho and Pentaho Metadata Editor (PME) 5.1.0. I created a domain in PME with tables, relationships, security, etc. and published it to the Pentaho server. I can see this Domain as a datasource of type 'Metadata' when I go to 'Manage Datasources' in the Admin console. However my Domain does not appear as a source when I try to create a new Pivot4J view.

I do see the Pentaho demos (Sampledata and Steel Wheels) in Pivot4J but I do not see my domain/metadata. I also edited the PentahoObject.spring.xml file to remove security on metadata objects as suggested in the Pentaho doc. Same thing for Saiku. What is the step that I am missing here?

Comment: It's obviously something wrong in your mondrian xml. Would you publish it?
An easier way is to create cube via Pentaho data-source wizard.

Comment: As per the answer I got on the Pentaho forum - PME will create a file that is accessible only to Report Designer and Report Analyzer - it does not create the Mondrian XML file. Pentaho Schema Workbench (PSW) creates the Mondrian file. I was able to create an xml file in PSW and publish to the server and work on it in Saiku.